# CSS - getting background color to fill drop down menu

Tags: html, css, xhtml

New to CSS. I have a nav menu bar and I am trying to fill the background color (blue) in the drop down menu under "portfolio" when you hover over it. Any ideas? I think its because of that absolute?

CSS:

```
#nav, #nav ul {
float: left;
list-style: none;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px #000000;
background-color: #F5F1DE;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
z-index: 100;
}

#nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
font-size: 1em;
}

#nav li a:hover {
color: black;
background-color: #bbecff;
}

#nav li {
float: left;
}

#nav li ul {
position: absolute;
width: 11em;
left: -999em;
border-radius: 1px;
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul {
left: auto; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Packages</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Weddings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Special Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Holidays</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fresh Flowers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Balloon Sculptures</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left` only for first child of `ul`.Update your following line of css:

```
#nav li {float: left;}
```

to

```
#nav > li {float: left;}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bNGfH/)

Comment: awesome that worked - but how would you get rid of that indent next to the home and under the submenu?

Comment: I fixed it - added padding 0px to #nav, #nav ul and to #nav li ul.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope it will work for u

add the CSS

```
#nav li ul{
background:#0066CC;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

give background color to the following

```
 #nav li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul {
    background-color: #bbecff; 
}
```

But with that said: Why don't you apply the `background-color` to the submenu `ul` directly?

Answer (score 0):

U may also try this, I hav given an `id` to respective li

```
 <li id=blueColor>
        <li><a href="#">Weddings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Special Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Holidays</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fresh Flowers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Balloon Sculptures</a></li>
    </ul>
```

In CSS

```
#blueColor:hover{
backgroung-color:blue
}
```

Comment: Working with IDs isn't necessary here.

Comment: @linus What's wrong if you provide the id??You can be more specific with it

Comment: Didn't say it is wrong, except you missed the " around the id. The ID is not needed, that's all.